# I want to de-dupe records in BigQuery with max column value on specific column with expression

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

```
company  | email | phone | website | address
Amar CO LLC | amar@gmail.com | 123 | NULL | India
Amar CO | amar@gmail.com | NULL | NULL | IND
Stacks CO | stack@gmail.com | 910 | stacks.com | United Kingdom
Stacks CO LLC | stack@gmail.com | NULL | NULL | UK
```

I want to drop the company name with `CO LLC` instead want to keep `Amar CO` but want all the columns from `Amar CO LLC` as it has `minimum NULL` values or maximum column data.

In short: De-dupe the records, remove the company name with 'ending with or matching with LLC' (case insensitive), but keep the values from both of the record which has maximum Information column.

Expected output

```
Amar CO | amar@gmail.com | 123 | NULL | India
Stacks CO | stack@gmail.com | 910 | stacks.com | United Kingdom
```

Comment: You should include more sample data to get the point across.  Also, is the `amar.gmai.com` a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to give precedence to the record having minimum null values ...

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL (query#1)

```
#standardSQL
select 
  array_agg(t 
    order by array_length(regexp_extract_all(to_json_string(t), ':null')) 
    limit 1
  )[offset(0)].* 
  replace(regexp_replace(company, r'(?i)CO LLC', 'CO') as company) 
from `project.dataset.table` t
group by company
```

if applied to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

> In case if you want to fill all fields from all the records - you can use below (query#2)

```
select regexp_replace(company, r'(?i)CO LLC', 'CO') as company,
  max(email) email,
  max(phone) phone,
  max(website) website,
  max(address) address
from `project.dataset.table`
group by company
```

> and finally - if you still want to give precedence to the record having minimum null values, but the rest of nulls replace with values from other rows  - use below (query#3)

```
select company, 
  ifnull(email, max_email) email,
  ifnull(phone, max_phone) phone,
  ifnull(website, max_website) website,
  ifnull(address, max_address) address
from (
  select array_agg(t 
      order by array_length(regexp_extract_all(to_json_string(t), ':null')) 
      limit 1
    )[offset(0)].* 
    replace(regexp_replace(company, r'(?i)CO LLC', 'CO') as company),
    max(email) max_email, 
    max(phone) max_phone,
    max(website) max_website,
    max(address) max_address
  from `project.dataset.table` t
  group by company 
)
```

you can test/check the difference between this and previous option by applying them to below dummy data

```
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select 'Amar CO LLC' company, 'amar@gmail.com' email, 123 phone, NULL website, 'India' address union all
  select 'Amar CO', NULL, 222, 'amar.com', NULL union all
  select 'Stacks CO LLC', 'stack@gmail.com', NULL, NULL, 'UK' union all
  select 'Stacks CO', 'stack@gmil.com', 910, 'stacks.com', 'United Kingdom'
)
```

the last query (query#3) gives

[image]

while previous (query#2) will just give max across all rows

[image]

Comment: masterpiece! exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You need `group by` and `replace` as follows:

```
select replace(company,' LLC','') as company, max(email) as email, max(phone) as phone,
       max(website) as website, max(address) as address
  from your_table t
group by replace(company,' LLC','')
```

I can see that you need all data of the both rows but precedence should be given to LLC record (`India, IND --> India`) then you can use it as follows:

```
select t.company, 
       coalesce(tt.email,t.emial) as email, 
       coalesce(tt.phone,t.phone) as phone
       coalesce(tt.website,t.website) as website,
       coalesce(tt.address,t.address) as address
  from your_table t join your_table tt 
    on concat(t.company,' LLC') = tt.company
```

If you want to update the data and then drop the record itself, I would suggest the following `delete` and `update`.

```
delete from your_table where t.company = 'Amar CO';

update your_table t
set t.comapny = replace(company,' LLC','') -- or use 'Amar CO'
where t.company = 'Amar CO LLC';
```

**-- Update**

You want to give precedence to the record having minimum null values then you can use the following query:

```
select t.company,
       case when tt_nulls > t_nulls then ttemail else temail end as email,
       case when tt_nulls > t_nulls then ttphone else tphone end as phone,
       case when tt_nulls > t_nulls then ttwebsite else twebsite end as website,
       case when tt_nulls > t_nulls then taddress else taddress end as address
from    
(select t.company, 
        count(case when t.email IS NULL THEN 1 end) over (partition by t.company) 
        + count(case when t.phone IS NULL THEN 1 end) over (partition by t.company) 
        + count(case when t.website IS NULL THEN 1 end) over (partition by t.company) 
        + count(case when t.address IS NULL THEN 1 end) over (partition by t.company)  
        as t_nulls,
        count(case when tt.email IS NULL THEN 1 end) over (partition by t.company) 
        + count(case when tt.phone IS NULL THEN 1 end) over (partition by t.company) 
        + count(case when tt.website IS NULL THEN 1 end) over (partition by t.company) 
        + count(case when tt.address IS NULL THEN 1 end) over (partition by t.company)  
        as tt_nulls
        t.email as temail, 
        t.phone as tphone,
        t.website as twebsite,
        t.address as taddress,
        tt.email as ttemail, 
        tt.phone as ttphone,
        tt.website as ttwebsite,
        tt.address as ttaddress
   from your_table t join your_table tt 
     on concat(t.company,' LLC') = tt.company) t
```

Comment: precedence is not given to `LLC record`, but the record which has maximum of RECORDS, i.e minimum NULL values/